# gitlab docker stop after few seconds because he can't reach postgres anymore

Tags: docker, ansible, connection, gitlab

So I'm using Ansible and created the gitlab role a month ago. It worked perfectly. I'm now trying to use it again (it uses the most recent release of gitlab if I understood well) but it stops the docker anytime I start it because of :

```
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused 
Is the server running on host "postgres" (172.18.0.3) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432.
```

Thing is I added in ufw the rule to allow any proto to this port and it was working a month ago.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I would bet **strongly** that your `postgres` container was restarted, and thus acquired a new IP address. The correct fix for that problem is to use `--link` between the two containers, or use `docker run --ip=` to _assign_ the `postgres` container a stable IP over time

Comment: Never restarted and even tho. It's going by the network I created with docker and every other container works perfectly

Comment: So you can connect to postgres on 172.18.0.3 from other containers but not gitlab?

Comment: Thing is I can't connect postgres from anywhere (well i can but get rejected as soon as I get in) but in the other way so from postgres to connect on any other docker I can. Thing is I found that my dockerfile is responsible because if I don't use it It works but my dockerfile is working the same way on production (it's only since now that it isn't working anymore in my test serv) here i my dockerfile :

Comment: FROM postgres:10.1
RUN apt-get update -y && \
apt-get install postgresql-plpython3-10 -y

Comment: If I removed it and call directly postgres 10.1 in my docker-compose it is working perfectly

Comment: If from postgres docker you can connect to any other docker but not inverse, maybe a firewall on the postgres docker blocking incoming packets? Or, if the problem are only to postgres and not to the docker itself, postgres not listening port?

Comment: Can you post your postgres container logs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found. To anyone having the same issue, i'm gonna set you free x)

The package I install in my dockerfile (postgresql-plpython3-10) upgrade a package named "postgresql" ... and obviously not the same version as I had in my image so it broke everything.

It was working before because the package was by luck the same version as my postgres at this time but not anymore.

Fix : find a way around to disable this upgrade or upgrade your postgres version (minor version are compatible with each other)